# How to slice off a string in Ruby using another string?

Tags: ruby, substring, text-manipulation

Say I have a sentence similar to the following:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I'd like to slice off everything before and including "jumps", so I am left with:

```
 over the lazy dog
```

Currently, I get the index of the part I'd like to remove, then add the length of that part to it, and then slice it, as such:

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
slice_index = sentence.index("jumps").to_i + sentence.size
sliced_sentence = sentence.slice(slice_index..-1)
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I like the regex solution, but

`sentence.split(" jumps ").last`

works too, even if there are multiple "jumps".

Comment: Thank you so much for the very simple solution! much better than all the complications I was going through to get the exact same result, and it addresses multiple matches. Much appreciated!

Comment: Using `rpartition` instead will be faster.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
sentence =~ /jumps(.*)$/
sliced_sentence = $1
#=> " over the lazy dog"
```

`jump` is the word you are looking for, `(.*)$` is everything until the end of the string and the brackets represent the first capturing group (which is therefore referenced as $1)

Comment: i'm hitting myself over the head for not thinking about using regular expressions! that would be the most intuitive approach, and so this question gets a one-up. However, I'm awarding to Kyle for his one-line solution using only Ruby functions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best solution but I would do it like so:

```
sentence = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
sentence.split(" jumps ")[1]
```

split divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array of these substrings. array index 1 will always be the section after the delimiter. This breaks if there are more than one " jumps "